# Making the value of an array a list of numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I have to create a program that plays an elimination game. The user has to input the number of players and the number of "cycles" or how much the program counts by. So for example if I input 8 players and 4 cycles then the first player out will be player 4 and then the next one would be player 8, and then it goes on and on until there is one winner. I am trying to make a list of numbers starting from 0 and going to the number of players the user inputs. I was able to get an array with the number of players but all the numbers are 0's. So for example if a user enters 4 players the program is supposed to go "0,1,2,3" but mine goes "0,0,0,0" how can I fix this? The while loop where I make the array is on lines 15 to 19, so I have a feeling the problem is in those lines. Also please ignore the rest of the code for now as I am trying to get this correct before I move on. Well thank you in advanced and here is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class numberPicker 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
 String cycles = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the number of cycles");
 int cyclesUse = Integer.parseInt(cycles);
 String players = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the number of players");
 int playersUse = Integer.parseInt(players);
 String arrayUse = "";
 int count = 0;
 int[] array = new int [playersUse];

 while(count < playersUse)
 {
   count++;
  arrayUse = Arrays.toString(array);
 } 

  int countUp = 0;

  while(countUp < playersUse)
  {
    countUp++;
  }

 int addition = 0;
 int counter = 0;

  while(counter < 999)
  {
  counter++;
  addition++;
  if(addition == cyclesUse)
  {


  }

  if (addition > cyclesUse)
  {
    addition = 0;
  }
}
  System.out.println(arrayUse);
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are handling an empty array. You need to fill it before casting to string. For example, like this:

```
while(count < playersUse)
{
    array[count] = count;
    count++;
}

arrayUse = Arrays.toString(array);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I was trying to do.